# If string contains in filename, then add value to column (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filenames, glob

I'm trying to add a month column with values to an existing Excel-File (xlsx). With the if statement, it's supposed to add a specific month based on the string in the file name. Despite not receiving an error, my function seems to have problem looking up the filename (it works however if I do something like 'if "jan" in "monthjanmonth").

```
sale14_file = pd.read_excel("sales-jan-2014.xlsx")
File_Name = glob.glob("sales-jan-2014.xlsx")

# adding date as first column
def AddingDate():
    if "jan" in File_Name:
        CustomMonth = "January"
        sale14_file.insert(0, "Date", CustomMonth)

AddingDate()
```

IDE: pycharm

Python version: 3.0

Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_handler = open('sales-jan-2014.xlsx','w')
file_handler.close()

File_Name = glob.glob("sales-jan-2014.xlsx")
type(File_Name)
print('{0}'.format(File_Name))


x = "jan" in File_Name
print('{0}'.format(x))

x = "jan" in str(File_Name)
print('{0}'.format(x))

x = "jan" in File_Name[0]
print('{0}'.format(x))
```

result

```
['sales-jan-2014.xlsx']
False
True
True
```

This is a list :) you need to use str() or change your code

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the answer myself. Had to add "str" to the filename variable.

```
File_Name = str(glob.glob("sales-jan-2014.xlsx"))
```

instead

```
File_Name = glob.glob("sales-jan-2014.xlsx")
```